# DataPicker: how remove year

Tags: ios, xcode

Good day! 
Help to understand pls.
How to datapicker remove  year?
all mode - not suitable

> ```
> number|month
> ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to have simply month and day as choices in a stock `UIDatePicker`.

You may, however, be able to subclass it yourself to provide the behavior you desire.